# How to update the data in the view when observable data gets updated?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-changedetection

I am subscribing to an observable (getContentfulEntry) to get some data but also passing the data from another observable (stateService)

```js
this.langSubscription = this.stateService.getLanguage()
      .subscribe(val => {
        this.lang = val;
      });
      
    this.subscription = this.contentfulService.getContentfulEntry(this.footerEntryId, {locale: this.lang.toLowerCase()})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Footer Entries:: ', res);
        // this.contentfulData = res;
        this.filteredFooter = this.contentfulService.getFilteredEntryByProv(res, this.prov);
        console.log('Filtered Footer:: ', this.filteredFooter);
      });
```

to it as a parameter. So new data is fetched when this.lang is updated. However, this.subscription doesn't update the data in the view unless I hit refresh on it. Any idea what am I doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: `{{lang}}` should update on view... what you have on html?

Comment: {{lang}} does update. I need the data that is being passed through this.filteredFooter updated as well.

Comment: <footer [data]="filteredFooter"></footer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the value of the data returned from stateService.getLanguage() (possibly) before getLanguage() has returned a value.

Ensure that this.lang has a value by making your call to getContentfulEntry()  within your subscription to getLanguage(). This will ensure that this.lang has a value when calling getContentfulEntry()

```
this.langSubscription = this.stateService.getLanguage()
  .subscribe(val => {
    this.lang = val;
    this.subscription = this.contentfulService.getContentfulEntry(this.footerEntryId, { locale: this.lang.toLowerCase() })
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Footer Entries:: ', res);
        // this.contentfulData = res;
        this.filteredFooter = this.contentfulService.getFilteredEntryByProv(res, this.prov);
        console.log('Filtered Footer:: ', this.filteredFooter);
      });
  });
```

You could also consider assigning the returned value from getLanguage() to a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html) (from rxjs) which acts as an Observable. You are able to subscribe to your BehaviorSubject, which will emit a value every time a new value is assigned. I mention behavior subjects as a way to manage parameters that might change over time, but don't consider this solution best practice in this use case.

```
lang = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

this.langSubscription = this.stateService.getLanguage()
  .subscribe(val => {
    // this.lang will emit the next assigned value "val"
    this.lang.next(val);
  });

// subscribe to emitted value from this.lang
this.lang.subscribe(val => {
  this.subscription = this.contentfulService.getContentfulEntry(this.footerEntryId, { locale: this.lang.getValue().toLowerCase() })
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Footer Entries:: ', res);
      // this.contentfulData = res;
      this.filteredFooter = this.contentfulService.getFilteredEntryByProv(res, this.prov);
      console.log('Filtered Footer:: ', this.filteredFooter);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was just looking into the BehaviourSubject! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

As api calls in angular are asynchronous, the call to api getContentFulEntry() happens before the call to getLanguage() completes. Your fulentry call is taking the same language and hence even the api call is going on, it is not updated on UI as if you see in browser console it passes the old language value. 
 So please call the second method once first completes.

Comment: "As api calls in angular are asynchronous" -- API calls _everywhere_ are asynchronous.